# Javascript if equals higher than 5

Tags: javascript

So I have a counter setup and I want to make it auto click a report button if the count goes higher than 5, this is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if(counter > 5){
document.getElementById("report-post-submit").click();
}
```

anyone have any idea why its not working?

UPDATED WITH FULL CODE:

```
var counter = 0
var timer;
function countUP () {
 counter = counter + 1;//increment the counter by 1
 //display the new value in the div
 document.getElementById("timer_container").innerHTML = counter;
}

    if(counter > '5'){
document.getElementById("wp-report-post-submit").click();
}


<body onload='timer=setInterval("countUP()", 1000 );'>
<div id="timer_container">0</div> 

<a class="report-post-button" id="report-post-submit"><?php _e("Send Report"); ?></a>
```

Comment: Have you debugged it? 
What is supposed to happen when the button is clicked?

Comment: it automatically sends a report to my email.

Comment: 1) counter is less or equals 5, 2) `document.getElementById("report-post-submit")` return unedfined, so can't find element with id _"report-post-submit"_ 3) not set click handler and etc

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong with the code, so again, have you made sure that `counter` is actually greater than 5? Post the complete code instead of just a snippet.

Comment: @DanielB I just updated my post with the full code

Comment: `doesn't seem to work` isn't a proper problem statement. We don't know what part isn't working or what you have done to troubleshoot. Why are you comparing number to string?

Comment: Your `if` will only run once on page load also. You aren't calling it after that

Comment: @charlietfl ok, how can I make it check every second?

Comment: @user3082412 just move checking inside _countUP_

Comment: @Grundy I did that and it stopped my counter from going up

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.

Check commented out lines:

```js
var counter = 0
var timer;
function countUP () {

  // set onclick event if it's not appended to the element:
  // document.getElementById("report-post-submit").onclick = function(){
  //   doStuff('Stuff done!');
  // }
 
  //increment the counter by 1
  counter++;
  //display the new value in the div
  document.getElementById("timer_container").innerHTML = counter;
  
  // Move this into 'countUP' function, to check counter while counting (not on page load time):
  if(counter > 5){    
    // trigger click event applied to the button:
    // document.getElementById("report-post-submit").onclick();
    // or simply call the method right here:
    doStuff('Stuff done!');
  }
}

function doStuff(txt){
  // your function to be fired on click or when counter gets more than 5:
  alert(txt);
  // reset counter after the stuff is done:
  counter = 0;
  // or clear the interval:
  // clearInterval(timer);
}
```

```html
<body onload='timer=setInterval(countUP, 1000 );'>
  <div id="timer_container">0</div> 
  <!-- append 'onclick' event to the button (or set the event in script section) -->
  <a class="report-post-button" onclick="doStuff('Stuff done!');" id="report-post-submit">do stuff</a>
</body>
```